# What's the difference between rotate(angle) and Matter.Body.rotate(body, angle)? Using matter.min.js library. When & why should they be used together?

Tags: physics-engine, rotatetransform, matter.js

```js
const Engine = Matter.Engine;
const World = Matter.World;
const Bodies = Matter.Bodies;
const Body = Matter.Body;

var canvas, myEngine, myWorld;
var ball, ball_options;
var ground, ground_options;
var wedge, wedge_ops;
var angle = 50;

function setup() {
    canvas = createCanvas(400, 400);

    myEngine = Engine.create();
    myWorld = myEngine.world;

    wedge_ops = {
        'isStatic' : true
    }

    wedge = Bodies.rectangle(200, 300, 100, 20, wedge_ops);
    World.add(myWorld, wedge);
  
}

function draw() {
    background(0);

    Engine.update(myEngine);

    rectMode(CENTER);
    
    Body.rotate(wedge, angle);
    angle = angle + 0.1;

    push();
    angle = angle + 0.1;
    translate(wedge.position.x, wedge.position.y);
    rotate(angle);
    rect(0, 0, 100, 20);
    pop();
}
```

> I am unable to understand why we use 2 different rotate() functions?
> What's the difference between rotate(angle) and Matter.Body.rotate(body, angle)? Using matter.min.js library. When & why should they be used together?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your example isn't runnable, but my guess based on these functions is that you (or whoever's code this is...) are using p5.js alongside matter.js. p5.js defines functions like [rotate](https://p5js.org/examples/transform-rotate.html) in the global scope. Please provide a [mcve] and enough context to definitively answer the question. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your response! So I figured it out that we are using a physics engine body and a renderer in this case. rotate(angle) is to make the renderer rotate like the physics engine body moves due to Matter.Body.setAngle(angle). And to answer your question, yes, I'm using both p5.js and matter.js here. :)

Comment: No problem, thanks for clarifying. So is there any lingering confusion about the difference between the two rotate functions? Keep in mind Matter.js has an internal demonstration-oriented renderer, and p5.js is being used to replace it in this case.